# How to use an RSA public key as the primary key to a table in postgres

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, encryption

I have a data set that needs to be looked up by RSA public keys.  These keys are 392 text characters long.

What is the best way to make that a primary and/or unique key?

Should it be a BYTEA field?

Is it too long for a primary key?  Should I store a shorter hashed version of it to index on and filter by first before checking for an exact match?

Comment: If I were you, I would try and insert some sample data and test the performance hit of the long test PK on it.  If (and only if) I saw problems when reaching the expected amount of data, would I venture into some more complicated designs.  I wouldn't possibly choose bytea as the column type, and hashing might come handy.

Comment: Surely they are not really text?  I imagine they are actually a long string of hexadecimal characters?

Comment: @MaxVernon - The public keys are actually a binary blob that has been base64 encoded

Comment: so perhaps converting them back to binary before storing them would be more efficient and result in a less-wide key?

Answer (score 2):

I would say store them as `bytea`, but not for that reason. Simply because [`pg_crypto` expects the keys as bytea](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html). That establishes a convention. They likely have good reason for it: it seems intuitively faster.

Also there is no reason to store them as a `PRIMARY KEY`. You can sanely just store them in an indexed field.